# Why is an Array an AnyObject in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having trouble understanding the limitations of AnyObject.

You can see from the header that Array is a struct. Nevertheless, this code works:

```
var whatobject : AnyObject
whatobject = [1,2]
```

And it's not just literal arrays:

```
var whatobject : AnyObject
let arr = [1,2,3]
whatobject = arr
```

However, I can't assign a struct that I make to `whatobject`:

```
struct S {}
var whatobject : AnyObject
whatobject = S() // error
```

So an array isn't really a struct after all?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

that's the fun part when bridging comes in...

by default, Swift bridge

- `Int` (and friends) to `NSNumber`
- `String` to `NSString`
- `Dictionary` to `NSDictionary`

so compiler will change them to object if need to

and you can do

```
var num : AnyObject = 1 // I think num is now NSNumber
var arr : AnyObject = [1,2,3] // I think arr is now NSArray of @[@1,@2,@3]
```

---

and you can't assign `sturct`/`enum` to `AnyObject` because they are not object type (you can use `Any` to hold them)

Comment: Wow, I certainly hadn't thought of it that way before!

Comment: I hope Apple will change this kind of auto bridge behaviour. It introduced lots hard to find bugs.

Comment: Really? Can you give me an example?

Comment: structs are call by value and objects are call by reference, so you may modify (or not modify even you want to) something because you expect get a reference but get value (or other way around). it won't happen normally, but will cause you trouble when writing generic code. (I already give up to fight with compiler with some generic library code I want to write)

Comment: FYI, I get errors complaining about type conversions when I enter your code into a playground.

Comment: @BryanChen You can add type constraints to your generic functions to help with that.

Comment: @NateCook the problem I had is I have generic function take `NSObject` and use it `foo<Int>`, which was fine at start, but later for more complicated code, compiler refuse to take `Int` as `AnyObject` at some point

Comment: Playground execution failed: error: <REPL>:363:23: error: cannot convert the expression's type 'Int' to type 'AnyObject'
var num : AnyObject = 1 // I think num is now NSNumber
                      ^
<REPL>:364:23: error: cannot convert the expression's type 'Array' to type 'IntegerLiteralConvertible'
var arr : AnyObject = [1,2,3] // I think arr is now NSArray of @[@1,@2,@3]

Comment: @BergQuester you need to `import Foundation`

Comment: @BryanChen Derp, that's what I get for just dumping it into an existing playground.