# Using Swift functions in Objective-C that have protocol-typed parameters

Tags: swift

I have a Swift class called `Helpers` defined as follows:

```
class Helpers : NSObject {
    class func sayValue(value:Printable) {
        println(value)
    }
}
```

I am trying to use this in an Objective-C `.m` file, like so:

```
[Helpers sayValue:@"Hello"];
```

But the compiler is complaining with the error: `No known class method for selector 'sayValue:'`

However if I change the `sayValue` to have a strict type, it works fine:

```
class Helpers : NSObject {
    class func sayValue(value:String) {
        println(value)
    }
}
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've already figured it out. Swift protocols don't map as types into Objective-C.

Always just ask yourself "Could I say this in Objective-C?" You can't say this in Objective-C:

```
+ (void) sayValue: (Printable*) value { ... }
```

That's illegal, because Printable (a protocol) isn't a type. So your Swift function defined that way doesn't magically map upward into Objective-C, as it has nothing to map to. It is filtered out, and Objective-C never sees it.

What I'm finding is that all this works remarkably cleanly. I was afraid that a Swift class that uses *any* non-Objective-C features wouldn't map to an Objective-C class *at all*. But, on the contrary, you can use all the pure-Swift features you like, and they simply don't map up into Objective-C: they are cleanly filtered out, and those parts of your Swift class that *do* map into Objective-C work just fine from Objective-C. It's quite brilliant.

---

You are free to define a protocol that maps as a type for purposes of, say, defining a delegate. But to do that, you must expose the protocol using `@objc`. For example, from one of my apps:

```
@objc protocol ColorPickerDelegate {
    func colorPicker (/*...*/)
}

class ColorPickerController : UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: ColorPickerDelegate?
    // ...
}
```

You can't talk that way unless the protocol is `@objc`. Now Objective-C understands the type of `delegate` to mean `id<ColorPickerDelegate>` and you're in business.

(So you could probably talk the way you're suggesting by defining an `@objc` protocol MyPrintable which does nothing but adopt Printable; I haven't tried it, however, so that's just a conjecture.)

Comment: Thanks @Matt. What about a function that takes an `Any` type parameter? I would think that would map to `id` in Objective-C, but I get the same error as the one above. Is there a way to write a function in Swift that takes an `Any` type, and can still be used in Objective-C?

Comment: It would probably map to Obj-C if the protocol were a `@class_protocol`.

Comment: I answered my own question. Got it working using `AnyObject` in the Swift function to magically get bridged to `id` in objc.

Comment: @JamieForrest Right, AnyObject and id are bridged to one another. Basically that is what AnyObject is; in fact, as far as I can tell it only works properly in the presence of Objective-C. See my question here along with the answer and commentary thereon: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24154304/why-is-an-array-an-anyobject-in-swift

Comment: You can also have your Swift protocol extend (?) NSObject rather than re-casting or re-extending in ObjC