# Xcode6 beta 4 downcast to float

Tags: swift, xcode6

I have a `Dictionary` with a `String` and `AnyObject`, so `[String: AnyObject]`.

In a function I want to check the type of the dict value. So this code worked in Xcode6-Beta 3:

```
for (key, value: AnyObject) in contents {
    ...
    } else if value is Float {
        stringValue = String(value as Float) + ","
```

Now I get the error: `AnyObject is not convertible to Float`

`stringValue = String(Float(value)) + ","` doesn't work as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure, but are you sure can you cast to primitives?

Comment: @Logan that's incorrect see my answer

Comment: @wumm - I see, I removed my comment.

Comment: see my answer it has correct explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There is no problem with casting `AnyObject` to `Float`**.

Converting `AnyObject` to `Float` has no problem as you can see below instruction will execute without errors.

```
   var f:Float = value as Float
```

As swift `String` has no `intializer` to convert for `Float`
If you do

```
 var str:String = String(f) //This will show error as swift has no intializer for Float
```

But Swift has only added intializer to `String` for `Int` to convert directly.There is not intializer for `Float`.

```
   var i:Int = value as Int
   var str:String = String(i) //this will run fine
```

Now to solve your problem you can do

```
    for (key, value: AnyObject) in contents {
        if(value is Int){
        }else if value is Float {
            //Take this in var and use
            var stringValue = "\(value as Float),"
        }
    }
```

In future `swift` may add the intializer for `Float` but currently there is no intializer.

Comment: For more refreance see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24154304/why-is-an-array-an-anyobject-in-swift

Answer (score 1):

Replace "as" with "as!" to force downcast.

Please, remember that you can use the forced form of the type cast operator (as!) only when you are sure that the downcast will always succeed, otherwise a runtime error will be triggered. In your particular case there will be no problem since there is a previous checking (if value is Float).

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast to float because:

> AnyObject can represent an instance of any class type.

[From Swift Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html)

But `float` isn't a class. You will have to use `Any` instead:

> Any can represent an instance of any type at all, apart from function types.

[From Swift Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html)

This should work (but I can't test on my current Mac):

```
for (key, value: Any) in contents {
    ...
    } else if value is Float {
        stringValue = String(value as Float) + ","
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I get the same error ;) "Any is not convertible to Float"

Answer (score 0):

As wumm said, you can't directly cast to Float because Float is not a class type. You may be able to cast it to an NSNumber and bridge to a Float though. Try

```
value as NSNumber as Float
```

This strategy works with casting AnyObject into a Swift String.

Using your code and fixing the concatenation it would look like:

```
for (key, value: AnyObject) in contents {
    if value is Float {
        stringValue = "\(stringValue) \(value as NSNumber as Float) ,"
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you change your solution? "\\(value)" works! I don't want to bridge to old NSObjects

Comment: "\(value)" probably works because it doesn't try to cast to float. It may interpret it as an NSNumber and have the ability to use its string  representation