# Swift AnyObject's subscript, where did it come from?

Tags: swift, anyobject

In Swift, how is it that `AnyObject` supports subscripts, even for types that are't subscriptable? Example:

```
let numbers: AnyObject = [11, 22, 33]
numbers[0]       // returns 11

let prices: AnyObject = ["Bread": 3.49, "Pencil": 0.5]
prices["Bread"]  // returns 3.49

let number: AnyObject = 5
number[0]        // return nil

let number: AnyObject = Int(5)
number[0]        // return nil
```

Yet if my `number` is declared as `Int` then it's a syntax error:

```
let number: Int = 5
number[0]        // won't compile
```

Interestingly, `Any` doesn't have subscript support.

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24154304/why-is-an-array-an-anyobject-in-swift

Comment: The question is very interesting to understand the things behind the scenes but fairly theoretical. In practice you wouldn't use a type annotation `AnyObject` for an object whose proper type the compiler can infer and you - the developer - know exactly. Apple strongly discourages from using (such kind of) type annotations anyway.

Comment: `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData` returns `AnyObject`

Answer (score 13):

This works only if you import `Foundation`, as Swift is doing in that case some bridging to `Objective-C` types - a `NSArray`-like object in this case.

```
import Foundation

let numbers: AnyObject = [11, 22, 33] as AnyObject
type(of: numbers) //_SwiftDeferredNSArray.Type
```

If you don't import `Foundation`, then you are not even allowed to make the assignment (because a Swift array is a struct and not an object).

```
let numbers: AnyObject = [11, 22, 33] // error: contextual type 'AnyObject' cannot be used with array literal
```

You can cast to `Any`, though:

```
let numbers: Any = [11, 22, 33]    
type(of: numbers) // Array<Int>.Type
```

---

Why does the `import Foundation` does the trick? This is documented in the `AnyObject` type description:

```
/// When used as a concrete type, all known `@objc` methods and  
/// properties are available, as implicitly-unwrapped-optional methods  
/// and properties respectively, on each instance of `AnyObject`.  For  
/// example:  
///  
///     class C {  
///       @objc func getCValue() -> Int { return 42 }  
///     }  
///  
///     // If x has a method @objc getValue()->Int, call it and  
///     // return the result.  Otherwise, return nil.
```

This means you can even call methods on your array that don't necessarily exist on `NSArray`, but exists in the `Objective-C` world, like for example:

```
numbers.lowercaseString       // nil
```

and Swift will gracefully return you a `nil` value instead of throwing you a nasty `object does not recognises selector` exception, like it would happen in Objective-C. If this is good or bad, remains to debate :)

**Update**
The above seems to work only for properties, and property-like methods, if you try to use an Objective-C method, then you'll run into the unrecognized selector issue:

```
import Foundation

@objc class TestClass: NSObject {
    @objc var someProperty: Int = 20
    @objc func someMethod() {}
}

let numbers: AnyObject = [11, 22, 33] as AnyObject
numbers.lowercaseString                // nil
numbers.someMethod                     // nil
numbers.someMethod()                   // unrecognized selector
numbers.stringByAppendingString("abc") // unrecognized selector
```

Comment: Great finds and a great answer.  My answer assumes Foundation has been imported.  Thank you for a pure Swift explanation!

Answer (score 5):

It has to do with the bridging of types when assigning a value to an object of type `AnyObject`:

```
let numbers: AnyObject = [11, 22, 33]
print(numbers.dynamicType) // _SwiftDeferredNSArray.Type

let prices: AnyObject = ["Bread": 3.49, "Pencil": 0.5]
print(prices.dynamicType) // _NativeDictionaryStorageOwner<String, Double>.Type

let number: AnyObject = 5
print(number.dynamicType) // __NSCFNumber.Type

let anotherNumber: Int = 5
print(anotherNumber.dynamicType)  // Int.Type
```

Behind the scenes, `_SwiftDeferredNSArray.Type`, `_NativeDictionaryStorageOwner<String, Double>.Type`, and `__NSCFNumber.Type` must support subscripts while `Int.Type` does not.

This is assuming you have imported Foundation.  For an explanation with pure Swift types, see [Cristik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34935706/2415822).